# mongo sorting with pagination

Tags: mongodb, sorting, paging

I have a need to implement paging in my `mongodb` collection. This is an example of a document in my collection

```
{
  "_id" : "<Mongo Generated>",
  "category" : "abc",
  "createdDate" : "<Date of creation of the document>",
  "markedDate" : "<Date when the document is marked 
               (marking is an activity that is done via my application>"
}
```

This is my requirement:

1. I need to retrieve all documents in category "`abc`", however in pages of 10 documents per page
2. The paging should be done only after the documents are sorted - I have to sort the documents by `markedDate` (Descending) first, then `createdDate` (descending)
3. A limit of 10 results should be applied
4. I should be able to skip to any page based on the page number that comes in the input

I tried to execute the following query to sort results using aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('testcollection').aggregate(
   {$match:{"category" : "abc"}}, 
   {$sort:{markedDate: -1, createdDate : -1}
})
```

However, how do I page? I can use a skip + limit option, however I went through some posts before posting this question, and it is not recommended for large data sets. I am anticipating that my collection with have around 75000 documents.

Also, since my date is stored in ISO date format, I see that the visibility is only at the level of seconds. I may have 2 documents created at the same second.

What's the best way to page my results without causing a performance impact?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sort function directly

```
db.testcollection.find({}).sort({createdDate:-1}).skip(1).limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, per Mongo documentation, using skip on large collection causes a deterioration in performance. I am looking at options to avoid this. I am looking at options to avoid this.                                  Any options?

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, per Mongo documentation, using skip causes a performance deterioration for large collections.

Comment: Its not just mongo  in general if you have large collection and you want a pages beyond 100/10000 its overhead for the database to fetch first n skip + limit, and then discard the skip count to show last limit number.